# Unzip archive and bzip2 it in memory?

Tags: python-3.x

How would you unzip an archive (`x.zip`) containing a single file (`x.txt`) and then bzip2 it in memory only writing the resulting bzip2 file to disk?

```
a.zip(a.txt) -> a.txt.bz2
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

I generalized the solution to a zip file containing one or more files without a directory structure.

```
import bz2
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile("files.zip", 'r') as zf:
    files = zf.namelist()
    for fn in files:
        f_bz2 = bz2.compress(zf.read(fn))
        with bz2.open(f"{fn}.bz2", "wb") as f:
            f.write(f_bz2)
```